# email adress on facebook app

Tags: email, facebook, delete

How do I make the facebook app "forget" my e-mail address? It's driving me insane... Since I'm a little paranoid, it seems that if I lose my phone, all anyone has to do is to enter my password into my "undeleteable" facebook app e-mail login address.

So, am I clear enough? I've tried clearing the data, clearing the cache, but EVERYTIME I open the facebook APP, THERE'S MY FREAKIN' E-MAIL ADDRESS!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your email address is stored as part of a "user account" on the device.

Settings => Accounts => Facebook : Menu => Remove Account

After clearing your cache and data for the app, and removing the account, your email should be removed. But, every time you log in it will add the account back into the settings.